# Using Aggregate Function in a Join

Tags: plsql

I am trying to use an aggregate function, COUNT, in a join.  However, there seems to be a problem with what I've written, and I keep getting error messages.  Here is what I have so far:

```
select  a.firstname, a.lastname, iddonor, count(idpledge)
  from dd_donor a inner join dd_pledge b
  using(iddonor)
  group by (iddonor);
```

I want to count the number of pledges made by each donor, and I want to group it by the donor's ID.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the other non-summary fields to the GROUP BY:

```
select  a.firstname, a.lastname, iddonor, count(idpledge)
  from dd_donor a inner join dd_pledge b
  using(iddonor)
  group by (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, iddonor)
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c66df/1)

Share and enjoy.